# Sub domain for specific region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, subdomain

I have purchased my domain(artykart.com) from GoDaddy.I want to add a subdomain to the existing domain named india.artykart.com. I want to direct visitors from India to the subdomain (india.artykart.com) when they type in artykart.com. So basically I want to add a region-specific subdomain. My hosting is on google cloud platform.

Comment: Hello, can you please explain how are you hosting your website in Google Cloud  Platform? are you hosting your app in App Engine? are you serving a static website from Cloud Storage? Are you serving from a custom Compute Engine? Also which runtime are you using?

Answer (score 2):

DNS servers do NOT support geolocation-based redirects to a subdomain.

This means that your website artykart.com will need to use a Geolocation service. Then redirect the user to india.artykart.com.

You can have webservers running for the same domain name in different locations in the world. There are DNS servers such as AWS Route 53 which offer geolocation but for a domain, not a redirect to another domain/subdomain. With Route 53 you can have a website in major world locations and use Route 53 to send traffic to a webserver serving that region.

Note: Geolocation is not a reliable service. This is a best-case guess by the geolocation service. An IP address location for major companies such as Google is the company's registered mail address and not by the data center that the IP is used.

Neither GoDaddy DNS nor Google Cloud DNS offers these services.